# looping through split numbers javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have this function, I want to loop through both of the strings and 
receive a return value for compareNumber that's closest to it - that is            (compareNumber +1) but only if none of it's digits are equal to any of searchNumber's digits. If any of compareNumber's digits are equal to any of searchNumber's digits, I need to fins the first value bigger than compareNumber that's not equal to any of searchNumber's digits.

```js
function compareNumbers(searchNumber, compareNumber){ 
  var isEqual = true;
  var digitsCompare = compareNumber.toString().split('');
  searchNumber.toString().split('').forEach(function(num,index) {
    if(!(num===digitsCompare[index])){
      isEqual = false;
    } 
  });
  return isEqual; 
} 

var b = compareNumbers(123,124);
console.log(b);
var d = compareNumbers(123,123); 
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Your question sounds a little convoluted and difficult to understand: can you give us a combination of numbers and the *expected* output?

Comment: do you have some more examples?

Comment: For ex. if searchNumber = 11 and compareNumber = 13, I need a return value for compareNumber which is the closest bigger value than 13 but none of its digits should be equal to searchNumber's digits. ( Result here should be 20);

Comment: In your example `compareNumbers(123, 124)` the return value would have to be `400` since all values from 123 to 399 all have either a '1', '2', or a '3' in the digits? Is that correct?

Comment: Basically I want to iterate through compareNumber and add  1 -> if (searchNumber.toString().split() !== compareNumber.toString().split())

Comment: @jwatts1980  That's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to consider this mathematically, as opposed to just adding `1` forever until you find a number that works.

The solution below iterates through each individual digit, increasing it by `1` until we find a digit we're allowed to use. Once we make that change, we know the rest of the digits will be replaced with the lowest number available to us.

Think of it like a combination lock, except as soon as you turn one dial, all the ones after it reset to the lowest number we're allowed to use.

```js
function compareNumbers(n1, n2) {
  var n1Array = ("" + n1).split("").map(Number);
  var n2Array = ("" + n2).split("").map(Number);
  var availableNumbers = [...Array(10).keys()].filter(n => !n1Array.includes(n));

  //Loop through each digit in our compare string
  n2Array.some((n, index) => {
    let originalN = n;
    
    //Increment it until we have a valid number
    while (!availableNumbers.includes(n)) 
      if (n < 9)  n++
      else {
        //If we've passed 9, then we need to use the lowest number *twice*
        //However, if we're changing the first number, we CAN'T replace it with a 0
        n = Number((index === 0 ? availableNumbers[0] || availableNumbers[1] : availableNumbers[0]).toString() + availableNumbers[0]);
        break;
      }

    if (originalN !== n) {
      n2Array[index] = n;
      var replacements = n2Array.splice(index + 1).map(n => availableNumbers[0]);
      n2Array = [...n2Array, ...replacements];
      return true; //Exit early
    }

    return false;  //Keep iterating
  });

  //Turn [4,0,0] into 400
  return Number(n2Array.join(""));
}

let result1 = compareNumbers(123,124);
console.log(result1);

let result2 = compareNumbers(123,423);
console.log(result2);
```

A lot of the scrappy/ugly stuff is to account for edge-cases.

The first edge-case being that if we increase a `9`, then it shouldn't become a `10`, but rather the lowest number available to us *repeated twice*.

However, there is an edge-case *within* that. If our lowest number available is `0`, and `9` is our first number, we can't replace it with `00`. Otherwise, you could end up with `915` becoming `0015`.

Answer (score 0):

The code is below:

```js
function compareNumbers(searchNumber, compareNumber) {
  //error check the args
  var searchString = searchNumber + "";
  var compareString = compareNumber + "";

  if (compareString.length === 0) return "nope";
  var compareInt = parseInt(compareString) + 1;
  if (searchString.length === 0) {
    return compareInt;
  }

  //don't crash the app
  if (searchString.length >= 10 
    && searchString.indexOf("0") >= 0 && searchString.indexOf("1") >= 0 
    && searchString.indexOf("2") >= 0 && searchString.indexOf("3") >= 0 
    && searchString.indexOf("4") >= 0 && searchString.indexOf("5") >= 0 
    && searchString.indexOf("6") >= 0 && searchString.indexOf("7") >= 0 
    && searchString.indexOf("8") >= 0 && searchString.indexOf("9") >= 0 ) {
      return "nope";
  }

  while(containsDigits(searchString, compareInt)) {
    compareInt++;
  }

  return compareInt;
}
    
function containsDigits(digits, intVal) {
  var strVal = intVal + "";
  var strDigits = digits + "";
  for(var i = 0; i < strDigits.length; i++) {
    if (strVal.indexOf(strDigits.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// Examples
pairs = [[123, 124], [11, 13], [25, 35], [15, 21], [138, 546], [1, 2], [1, 1]];
pairs.forEach((pair) => console.log(`Compare [${pair[0]}, ${pair[1]}]: ${compareNumbers(pair[0], pair[1])}`));
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to split a string to access its contents as an array.

```
var digitsCompare = compareNumber.toString();
console.log(digitsCompare.charAt(0)); <-- first char
```

Comment: You would have to use `split` if you wanted to return an array on which you could iterate.

Comment: I'm not sure this really moves OP any closer to a solution.